# Why is this MS Access question too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

I just saw and answered a question. To my surprise, the question was closed as "too broad":

[How to have children form with Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48385910/87698)

I have some experience on SO (> 100k rep), and I have cast a lot of close votes myself, but I just can't see why this question has been considered "too broad" by the community: It contains a clear problem description (maybe not perfect English, but, well, I'm not a native speaker myself), the OP did research (and did not find anything because he lacked the correct terminology) and, as it turns out, there is a clear answer to the OP's problem.

What did I miss?

Comment: I agree. Seems like a reasonable question. And, even though the OP didn't have the correct term to hand, he did a pretty good job of explaining what he meant.

Comment: It popped up in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40917798#40917798). I have pinged the close voters to share their reasoning here.

Comment: The title suggests the question could be very broad.  That may have confused some users who could not decode the OP's requirement.  But also, seems to be a pretty basic question.  Are you sure there isn't a duplicate?

Comment: @psubsee2003: While not "Too Broad", it does seem to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174473/open-form-with-modal-or-popup-window)

Comment: It came across as unclear and broad to me, hence my VTC. While the eventual answer was modal, I did not draw that conclusion when I first read it and moved on. I don't however understand the down votes on your answer though.

Comment: Here is my take on it: after the first reading the question does seem to be too broad. It's a bit fluffy and the title is unclear / misleading. However, only after some discussion in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40917798#40917798) room and a **second** reading it does appear to be a modal form problem gone wrong. I can understand the confusion but the wording is partially to blame.

Comment: @Ron This is why you should be closing as Unclear when you are having trouble understanding a question, rather than Too Broad.

Comment: @Servy I am not one of the voters on that one but you raise a valid point.

Comment: @Servy but even when I vote unclear, when there are already 4 Tb votes and I vote unclear it takes the majority.

Comment: Let's not go into technicalities. It's closure as any other reason then duplicate was probably wrong. Please address that.

Comment: @rene What's wrong about voting to close as unclear question as unclear?

Comment: @Servy nothing, I was a bit worried that the discussion would end in  a debate about which close notice in the end  would appear on the question, unclear, off-topic/no mcve or too broad.

Comment: duplicate works fine with me, it will give some extra answers to that "a bit unclear" question

Comment: But... you can't *have* children with Access. It's a program, not a person. I'm confused.

Comment: @Will. Hah. Next you'll say is Siri isn't a person too.

Comment: Wait until the OOP AIs start breeding. And we already have genetic algorithms.

Answer (score 17):

I was the one bringing it up on SOCVR and casting the first close vote. My reasoning was as follows:

I'll bring in a few parts of the question, and explain my reasoning.

> ### How to have Access show a child form which the user must interact with?
>
> First, I'm not sure if children forms, or child form, are the correct terms for what I want, so maybe that's why I didn't find anything.

The OP is clearly not sure how to call things by their name. We don't know if he's talking about subforms (which I assumed), or other forms.

> I have a main form in Access. It has buttons to open other forms. I would like to prevent the user from toggling between forms.

That's pretty unclear. OP isn't sharing any code, and the most likely way to achieve this without code is the navigation control. And in that case, the forms could be seen as child forms (subform would be the more appropriate word).

But wait, is it? Or are all the buttons coded with macro's or VBA (code OP is not sharing), and are the forms not children at all, but just completely unrelated forms.

Or maybe it's something else altogether.

In my opinion, the OP hasn't *limited the question to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.*, the definition of too broad. I don't know enough about his setup to know he wants a modal form, or that he wants you to prevent changing tabs on a navigation control and he wants you to prevent changing form until data entry is complete, or that he wants something else altogether.

Your answer assumes that those *child forms* are completely unrelated to the main form. And your answer does not only prevent him from toggling between forms, but also makes him unable to use any other part of the database. I'm not sure that the assumption is correct, neither am I sure that the result is correct.

Of course, wrongfully tagging the question [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) didn't help too, but the reason I closed the question is that I don't know enough about the setup to adequately identify an answer, and that I see any answer on the question as speculation about what the OPs setup might be, and what he might want as an answer.

And honestly, you start your answer with *It sounds like you want*, which indicates you're not fully sure either

Comment: When you're unsure of what the OP is actually asking for it's really better to go with Unclear over Too Broad.  Sure, you can go with the reasoning of "trying to cover all of the possibilities that you left open would make the question too broad" but people tend to not interpret close reasons that way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I often doubt between those close reasons, and until now I've mainly used _unclear_ if the OP was not making sense at all and _too broad_ if I thought the question could be answered if OP added some details and specified what he wanted exactly, but I guess I should change that behaviour.

Comment: @Servy: Considering SO does not list each seperate close-reason, it might well be some of the CVers _did_ vote as "unclear". OTOH, one could argume that "too broad" for such an unspecific question is fine. Erik: I'm not sure which reason I picked, but I agree with your reasoning why the question should have been closed; I'll refrain from writing a seperate answer. +1

Comment: Too Broad is for things like Big List questions and questions that would take the better part of a book chapter to answer.

Comment: **"I have a main form in Access. It has buttons to open other forms. I would like to prevent the user from toggling between forms."** This clearly explains what OP want even though he does not share any code. He do not share any code may be because he do not know how to do it and that is why the question. Target duplicate and accepted answer correctly match.

Comment: @AmitJoshi How does that not describe a navigation control too? In that case, it makes sense to talk about children (since they're subforms). In this case it does not.

Answer (score 11):

I was one of the close voters. As rene [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362368/why-is-this-ms-access-question-too-broad#comment551136_362368), the question popped up in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40917798#40917798). I then looked over the question and it appeared slightly too broad to me, for similar reasons as Ron [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362368/why-is-this-ms-access-question-too-broad#comment551143_362368). Therefore, I voted to close. I neither down-voted the question, nor your answer.

After *your* question was mentioned in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40918464#40918464), I read the closed question again, more carefully. (Yes, I know, I should have done this right away.) Now I think it's okay-ish. I don't mind to admit that I might have made a mistake here. Therefore, I have cast the last reopen vote on that question. I'm sorry for the inconvenience!